# TypeScript definition file for existing node module

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, commonjs, typescript-typings

In my TypeScript project I want to use [Logdown](https://github.com/caiogondim/logdown.js).

Logdown can be used in a Node.js application like this:

```
var Logdown = require('logdown')
var logger = new Logdown({prefix: 'test'})
logger.info('Hello World');
```

Unfortunately, Logdown does not provide declarations, so I wanted to write a declaration file.

To kickstart this little project, I did the following:

- I cloned the Logdown repository
- I created a "typings" entry in the `package.json` file of the cloned Logdown repository and pointed it do `dist/logdown.d.ts` (according to "[Including declarations in your npm package](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html)")
- I made the cloned Logdown repository locally available as npm package (`npm link`)
- I ran `npm link logdown` within my TypeScript application to point this Node module reference to my cloned repository

After that I created the content for the `logdown.d.ts` file:

```
export declare class Logdown {
  constructor(options: Object);
  public info(text: string): string;
}
```

I was hoping that I can use now Logdown in my TypeScript project like this:

```
import Logdown = require("logdown");
let logger: Logdown = new Logdown();
logger.info('Hello World!');
```

But when I compile the project, I get the following errors:

> error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Logdown'.
>
> error TS2351: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.

Comment: It could be a simple typo: it's spelled `types` in `package.json`, not `typings`. Also, this does not works for typescript older than 2.0.

Comment: The setup is okay. Note that the "typings" field is synonymous with "types". I think the problem is located in `logdown.d.ts`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it working: I needed to change the export format to `export = Logdown;` in the definition file (`.d.ts`) and the import format to `import Logdown = require("logdown");` in my TypeScript application.

**Logdown.d.ts (Export Definition)**

```
declare class Logdown {
  constructor(options?: Object);
  public log(...args: string[]): void;
  public info(...args: string[]): void;
  public warn(...args: string[]): void;
  public debug(...args: string[]): void;
  public error(...args: string[]): void;
  public static disable(...args: string[]): void;
  public static enable(...args: string[]): void;
}

export = Logdown;
```

**TypeScript Application (Import)**

```
import Logdown = require("logdown");
...
let logger: Logdown = new Logdown();
logger.info('Hello from Logdown!');
```